# What apps use Java for user login?

Tags: java, authentication

Is there a website or app that uses Java for user login or anything related to the signing up process? Like I know for instagram, it is Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are many websites which use Java as part of their backend web technology, which includes the sign up process. Javascript is a language that is primarily used as part of a website's frontend and interpreted by your browser, and almost all websites use it in one way or another.

Comment: Can you give specific examples of the websites that use Java?